# I want to get the 20 records with the highest number of views + likes, how do I do in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema below:

[image]

I want to get the 20 records with the highest number of views + likes, how do I do in mongoose?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the actual JSON, not a picture of it. I noticed you edited your question to *remove* the JSON - not sure why, as that is the correct way to do it (though you should have made it properly formatted (there's a code-formatting button to help with this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#project-aggregation) to get the number of likes and pipe it with another project and [add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) the views and likes.

```
db.demo.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    likes: {
      $size: "$likes"
    },
    views: 1,
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    total: {
      $add: [
        "$likes", "$views"
      ]
    }
  }
},{ 
  $sort : { 
    total : -1
  } 
},{ 
  $limit : 20 
}])
```

Comment: Thank you. I did. 
I want to get 100 records with the highest total number of records.
But if I want to filter in 100 records according to conditions, it is not possible. I don't know how to combine aggregate with find (query)
Another problem is that after I get the last number of records, how do I get the total number of records?

Comment: Do not combine aggregate with find, use the `$match` in the pipeline to filter according to your preferences

Comment: Thank sir. But seem I don't see find(query) in your answer.
if I want to filter in 20 records according to conditions, it is not possible. I don't know how to combine aggregate with find (query)

Comment: Do you want to filter the last 20 records or you want to filter the entire collection to get 20 records?

Comment: I mean, I want to filter based on the conditions after I got 20 records with the highest number of views + likes.
Thank sir

Comment: This is a great answer! Just keep in mind that going down this route, you'll be scanning over all of the collection's index keys (or documents) to calculate the view/like counts. Aggregations are generally pretty performant, and this shouldn't be a problems for a small collection, but if performance starts being a problem, it might be worth following Erop's advice and creating and tracking a new "viewAndLikeCount" field that you can index.

Answer (score 0):

as I know there is no way to do that in one operation, but you could add a separate field with views + likes, and user sort desc + limit: 20

Comment: How can I get the number of elements of column "likes" each row? (the column "likes" is array)

Comment: ```db.post.find([
   { },
   { "$project": {
         "likes_size": { "$size": "$likes" }
   } },
])```

Comment: Currently I get size of "likes" column (likeCount). But what if I want to get all the columns of the table and add an "likeCount" column?
This is my code:
model.aggregate([{$project: { likes: true, view: true, likeCount: { $size : "$likes" + "$views" }}}], (err, documents) => console.info(documents))

Comment: `$size : "$likes" + "$views" ` that is wrong, as I said you can't do it in one request